# How can I integrate srcset in slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website contains a slideshow. I want to change the image, depending on the viewport size. This has been solved with following code:

```html
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="images/slider/4.gif" >
    <source media="(min-width:200px)" srcset="images/slider/4_m.gif" >
    <img src="images/slider/4.gif" alt="" style="width:auto;" >
</picture>
```

The image works, dependently on the viewport size. My problem - I want to integrate in this code here:

```html
<div class="slider-area">
    <div class="bend niceties preview-2">
        <div id="ensign-nivoslider" class="slides">
            'Following line should be replaced with code above...
            <img src="images/slider/4.jpg" alt="" title="#slider-direction-1"  /> 
            <img src="images/slider/5.jpg" alt="" title="#slider-direction-2"  />
            <img src="images/slider/6.jpg" alt="" title="#slider-direction-3"  />
        </div>
```

4th line should be replace by code above, but it doesn't work out. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use css style @ media screen for each screen's width

Comment: Nivo slider targets `<img>` elements for slides, so you can not use it here. Either use CSS and media queris, or change the slider library.

Comment: sorry, I am beginner in programming.. could you provide me more details? How should I adapt to my code?

Comment: I tried now following (not yet working)                                                              .image2{
   display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){ 
   .image1{
     display: none;
   }
   .image2{
     display: block;
   }
}                                                                                                                                                                                       <img src="images/slider/4.gif" class="image1" title="#slider-direction-1"/>
<img src="images/slider/4_m.gif" class="image2" title="#slider-direction-1"/>

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman - Give the man a link!  ;o)

Comment: @Paul ok :D
take alook here 
[RESPINSIVE images ( CSS TRIKCS )][1]


  [1]: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/